# Need help on Managed disk in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-managed-disk

I need some help with Azure Managed Disks:

1. How to generate SAS url/urli for managed disk?
2. How we can move the VHD/VM from one subscription to another subscription or from one location (westus) to another location (eastus)?
3. How we can de-provisioning the user/Generalized the managed disk VM while creating managed disk VM?
4. How I will get access or permission of one subscription because to move managed disk snapshot?

Comment: thats 4 questions, not one ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

If you were referring to export disk you can generate SAS token.

1. Select the Managed Disk
2. Disk properties select export disk
3. Click generate URL

then Azure will generate the URL for you

**Question 2**

1. Select the resource you want to move
2. Resource overview you can find the Resource group, there select change.
3. Select the resource group need to move

Note:- If the resource is depend on any dependencies need to move those resources too.

**Question 3**

Need more information what your trying to do :
I have to shared managed disk to some one by using SAS url?
How to create new VM from managed disk SAS url?

**Question 4**

Subscription Admin has to provide the relevant RBAC permissions to move snapshots. 
Eg:[VM Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#virtual-machine-contributor)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create new vm from managed disk sas url?

Comment: In that case you can create the SAS url mentioned in question 1 and share it, so he can download the disk from that url

you can't create a VM from that disk its for export disks. if you shared it to another person he can download it and then upload it to Azure and used it for VM creation

Comment: Thank you for clear information on managed disk. Can you please tell me how to upload the managed disk (GUI option like question1)

Comment: You can refer below link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed